# Swift Search Bar with Multiple Data

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tableview, searchbar

I have 5 labels that receive data from an array of SQL Query, in each cell on a `tableView`. I want to implement the search bar on it. Search bar should search through 1 specific label's data. it's working and filtering that specific label but when it's filtered, other 4 labels won't update and they are not changing at all. I can't figure it out. Since I have only 1 filtered data from search bar entry, I don't know how should I filter others.
Thanks

EDIT: Still can't figure it out about classes and adding data and i have an error of

> "Value of type '[String]' has no member
>   'localizedCaseInsensitiveContains'"

on searchbar function

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

var data:[MyData] = []
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
var searchActive : Bool = false
var filtered:[MyData] = []

@IBAction func sqlExecute(_ sender: AnyObject) {

var client = SQLClient()
    client.connect("sql_ip", username: "username", password: "password", database: "database") {
        success in

        if success {
            client.execute("sql query") {
                result in

                for table in result as Any as! NSArray {
                    for row in table as! NSArray {
                        for column in row as! NSDictionary {

                            if column.key as! String == "data1" {
                                MyData.init(data1: "\(column.value)")
                            } else if column.key as! String == "data2" {
                                MyData.init(data2: column.value as! Double)
                            } else if column.key as! String == "data3" {
                                MyData.init(data3: "\(column.value)")
                            } else if column.key as! String == "data4" {
                                MyData.init(data4: "\(column.value)")
                            } else if column.key as! String == "data5" {
                                MyData.init(data5: "\(column.value)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                client.disconnect()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(searchActive) {
        return filtered.count
    } else {
        return data.count
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "segue", for: indexPath)

    if(searchActive) {

        cell.label1.text = "\(filtered[indexPath.row])"
        cell.label2.text = "\(filtered[indexPath.row])"
        cell.label3.text = "\(filtered[indexPath.row])"
        cell.label4.text = "\(filtered[indexPath.row])"
        cell.label5.text = "\(filtered[indexPath.row])"
    } else {

    cell.label1.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
    cell.label2.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
    cell.label3.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
    cell.label4.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
    cell.label5.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    return cell
}


func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
    self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter { $0.data1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This is the class file:

```
import Foundation

class MyData {
var data1 = [String]()
var data2 = [Double]()
var data3 = [String]()
var data4 = [String]()
var data5 = [String]()


init(data1: String) {
    self.data1.append(data1)
}
init(data2: Double) {
    self.data2.append(data2)
}
init(data3: String) {
    self.data3.append(data3)
}
init(data4: String) {
    self.data4.append(data4)
}
init(data5: String) {
    self.data5.append(data5)
}
}
```

Comment: you only update label1 text from filtered Array, So other 4 labels text is not modified from filtered Array.Do you actually want this thing Or not.

Comment: I want to update them all at once. All label data are coming from the same SQL Query row so actually all labels are column values of the same row

Comment: but all others array are not change when you filter from Data1 and put it in filtered array.

Comment: you need to update all the others array if you want to apply some filteration on all the labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you have five different Array instead of that you need to have single Array of type `Dictionary` or maybe custom `Struct`/`class`. It is batter if you use `struct`/`class` like this.

```
class MyData {
    var data1: String!
    var data2: Double!
    var data3: String!
    var data4: String!
    var data5: String! 

    init(data1: String, data2: Double, data3: String, data4: String, data5: String) {
         self.data1 = data1
         self.data2 = data2
         self.data3 = data3
         self.data4 = data4
         self.data5 = data5
    }
}
```

Now instead of having five different array and one for filter create two `Array` of type `[MyData]` one of them is used for showing filterData and use that with `tableView` methods and filter it like this.

Create object of `MyData` using `init` method it and append its to the data Array then filter your in searchBar delegate like this.

```
filtered = data.filter { $0.data1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
```

The above filter will search in data array and return all objects thats property `data1` contains searchText.

Your whole code would be like this

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    var data:[MyData] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var searchActive : Bool = false
    var filtered:[MyData] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        } else {
            return data.count
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "segue", for: indexPath)

        if(searchActive) {

            cell.label1.text = filtered[indexPath.row].data1
            cell.label2.text = filtered[indexPath.row].data2
            cell.label3.text = filtered[indexPath.row].data3
            cell.label4.text = "\(filtered[indexPath.row].data4) ₺"
            cell.label5.text = filtered[indexPath.row].data5
        } else {

            cell.label1.text = data[indexPath.row].data1
            cell.label2.text = data[indexPath.row].data2
            cell.label3.text = data[indexPath.row].data3
            cell.label4.text = "\(data[indexPath.row].data4) ₺"
            cell.label5.text = data[indexPath.row].data5
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
        return cell
    }


    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filtered = data.filter { $0.data1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**Edit:** You need to use single array like this way.

```
for table in result as Any as! NSArray {
    for row in table as! NSArray {
        if let dic = row as? [String : Any] {
            let data1 = dic["data1"] as! String
            let data2 = dic["data2"] as! Double
            let data3 = dic["data3"] as! String
            let data4 = dic["data4"] as! String
            let data5 = dic["data5"] as! String
            let newData =  MyData(data1: data1, data2: data2, data3: data3, data4: data4, data5: data5)
            self.data.append(newData)
        }
    }
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I converted my code like your example but i can't append query results to MyData. It gives error of "Value of type [MyData] has no member of data1"

Comment: @fuzunspm Update your question with new code that you are using and show where you are getting this error.

Comment: @fuzunspm Check my MyData class it's proerty doesn't contains array you make custom class same way i have done.

Comment: @Nirav_D this time it works but the tableview won't populate. I think it's because we fill all cells with data[indexPath.row]

Comment: @Nirav_D it still returns empty. I also checked via print command and it's empty. does MyData.init method correct to append items?

Comment: @fuzunspm Are you still using multiple array inside MyData class? Also you need to use single init method with all data like my one

Comment: I can't use single init because I need to write SQL query results row by row like row1 = column1 + column2 + column3 + column4 + column5 and repeats until the last row so the number of cells should be amount of rows(or total amount of any column array since I don't write row numbers) and labels get their data from each row according to the their row number. I don't use arrays in MyData class.

Comment: @fuzunspm You need to do like my edited answer replace your for loop with my one and make only single init method like my method.

Comment: @fuzunspm Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make a global array then in search bar delegates sort it .

```
  extension  HVUserLisitingViewController  : UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return filterUser.count

    }
 } 
extension HVUserLisitingViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

        return true }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) { // called when text changes (including clear)
        webserviceSearchBy(text: searchBar.text!)
    }
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
          filterUser.removeAll()
          filterUser = users
          tableview.reloadData()
    }
    func webserviceSearchBy(text : String) {

        if text.lowercased().count == 0 {
            filterUser.removeAll()
            filterUser = users
            tableview.reloadData()
            return
        }
            filterUser.removeAll()

            filterUser = users.filter({ (user) -> Bool in


                if user.username.lowercased().range(of:text.lowercased()) != nil {

                    return true
                }
                return false
            })

            tableview.reloadData()
    }


}
```